# Do nested Bootstrap 3 rows need to be within a col-sm-*?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Do nested Bootstrap 3 rows need to be within a col-sm-* or can they also be nested within a col-md-*,  col-xs-*, etc?

The documentation says col-sm-* but it doesn't appear to be explicit about whether nesting within other col sizes is forbidden.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Documentation is not that clear there, but yes nested row can be in any col-xx-xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `col-sm-*`you're referring to is just an example. It should really be `col-*-*` (xs, sm, md, lg).

Have a look just further down where the describe pushing and pulling with `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*`. Once again it's just an example, any column can be pushed and pulled.

Furthermore, a nested row doesn't necessarily need to be directly within the parent column. The important thing to remember is that every row is directly followed by a column, but nested rows can be wrapped with any element.

Examples:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">OK</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="col-xs-12">NOT OK</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">OK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">OK</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all class in the same time. On this base bootstrap decide which one is the best for screen.

You can nasted class inside all of types - it's depend what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In TWBS3 the *`.col-xx-x`* classes only set width in terms of percentage, e.g. `.col-sm-4 { width: 25% }`, `.col-md-4 { width: 25% }` and `.col-md-4 { width: 25% }`.

Yes all the same, so you only need to define one.

But then why have all the variants?  Two reasons:

1. It's because you may want to have the columns render different widths at different resolutions, e.g. `.col-sm-4 .col-md-3` will render 1/4 width in small screen, but as 1/3 in medium, large and x-large screens.
2. The column will render down to it's 'mobile first' variant once the screen resolution falls below the chosen width.  i.e. `.col-sm-4` will render ¼ width in small, medium, lg, xl screens, but render full width at xs screens.  Similarly, using only `.col-md-4` with render 1/4 in md, lg & xl screens, but full width in sm & xs.  Therefore, a class set like `.col-sm-4 .col-md-4` is redundant.

So, with that knowledge - and in direct answer to your question: No, you only need one declaration, but be mindful of the size you select, as, when in smaller than your choice, the column will render full width (`width: 100%`)